# how to compare parameter value with a string in Azure yaml pipeline

Tags: azure, yaml, azure-pipelines

Parameter defined as -

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: deploy_images
    displayName: Publish images to Project Repository?
    type: string
    default: NO
    values:
      - sandbox
      - dev
      - production
```

Then following condition fails -

```
condition:  and( ne(${{ parameters.deploy_images }}, 'NO'), eq(${{ parameters.build_image }}, True))
```

Error -
##[error]Unrecognized value: 'sandbox'. Located at position 9 within expression: and( ne(sandbox, NO), eq(True, True)). For more help, refer to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=842996

Answer (score 1):

This works for me: `eq(parameters['deploy_images'], 'sandbox')`

Answer (score 1):

I had to use `condition` expression in the template to make it work.

Working template:

```
- job:
  condition: eq(variables['location'], 'ea')
  steps:
  - template: 'myTempl.yml'
    parameters:
      parm1: 'blah'
```

Template that doesn't work as expect:

```
- ${{ if eq(variables.location, 'ea') }}:
  - job:
    steps:
    - template: 'myTempl.yml'
      parameters:
        parm1: 'blah'
```

The condition in failed template is false, even if the value is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Provide single quotes around the expression:

```yaml
condition:  and( ne( '${{ parameters.deploy_images }}', 'NO'), eq(${{ parameters.build_image }}, True))
```

Also make sure, that 'NO' is actually among the values, that you allow for this parameter (I had to add it before it worked in my environment):

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: deploy_images
    displayName: Publish images to Project Repository?
    type: string
    default: NO
    values:
      - sandbox
      - dev
      - production
      - NO
```

Answer (score 0):

{{if eq('parameter.xxx', str}} or {{if eq(parameter.xxx, str)}} always fail, I have to use boolean